# Is there a way to enforce two types have same keys?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want the following two types - ViewModel  and SaveModel  to have same keys but different value types,

```
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string; 
  age: number;
}

type Address = {
  street: string; 
  zip: string;
}

type ViewModel = {
  user: User;
  address: Address;
}

type SaveModel = {
  user: number;
  address: string;
}
```

How to do this in typescript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there does not seem to be any relationship between the types of the properties in ViewModel and the types of the properties in SaveModel you can create a type that constrains a second type to have the same keys:

```
type MustHaveKeys<V, S extends Record<keyof V, any>> = S;

type SaveModel = MustHaveKeys<ViewModel, {
  user: number;
  address: string;
}>
type SaveModelBad = MustHaveKeys<ViewModel, {
  //user: number;
  address: string;
}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIyQG4c8yBDKiUuYRfMgc3pQmUFnw7lqdRI2wBfHDlCQoAQUKFEEOHFQZhXTRGCduvAUNxQAXvjAme-GfOyLw0AGr4IAdwCyAe0IIABtdLEsKBERSeAZhFnVNbVI1DS04JwVsJWhfSOAACRYANwgAaQgQOAAedwAaKABlKAgAD2AIMkIdACUIAGN-REJqgGtK-wAzKHqRMhAAPgXdRplXZUaSiACg0LQ8riLSiqrarz9AkIbwvEikUkpaOMsEtOSoAzMnBfXoTdKdiEAEIJXQHQpbE41Tw+QHBa7CAD0iLu0QkT2k8US6XsXxwsgWQA)

Comment: thanks Titian Cernicova-Dragomir!

Comment: In my case, I don't have a primary/secondary model, so I slightly changed your example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIyQG4c8yBDKiUuYRfMgc3pQmUFnw7lqdRI2wBfHDlCQoAQUKFEEOHFQZhXTRGCduvAUNxQAXvjAme-GfOwLsS6AGkIIHWgDkFAiIflAAPlB+LOqa2n4yiuDQALKBwAASLABuEF4+ADwAylAQAB7AEGSEOgBKEADGAPaIhHm5cAA0ImQgAHw9ugXxbolQAGr4EADuSQ2EEAA2uilcGdlteViWgUik8AzCURpacKRqR9pOPa7uUAVZEDNzi2jL6ffrm3jbiKSUtPuWQ4xE5QAxmS7XEZ3bKPBYAISiS1Sqxy3jgG2EAHpMVBvr9JAC8EDjvZwcJvgAmfH-aQ4WRXFzYIA, hope it is easier to add keys in any models first.

Comment: @ABOS That works as well